# Show content from database

Tags: database, front-end, views

This is my first post on Wordpress StackExchange, so please be gentle.

I’ve been working with WordPress for some time but more as a front-end developer and not too much back end dev. I have a background working in Joomla (don’t hold that against me...)

I am working on a current project, where an API is injecting data into a database, which the WordPress site has access to (it’s not been decided whether it is the WordPress database or an external database yet. The data is based around art works, so various data is associated with each piece of art and there will also require a search/filter option to look through the various data within the db.

My question is how can I get the data to show in the frontend of the site and use filtering/search and so on? Is there a plugin that I can use to look at the database and build pages for each category and then each piece of art? Or would something need to be built, if so, where do I start from a backend point of view?

I know I haven't put any code as to how I've tried to work this out myself so far, I'm only asking if this can be done and what the best way to achieve this is from a Wordpress best practice point of view.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You could use custom post types and custom taxonomies.

Using the custom post types to store data, taxonomies to categorize the data and you can utilize WordPress' default searching functionality.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies

https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page